# SignalR .Net Client can't establish conection (404 not found)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a solution in which i am using SignalR. There is a Hub in one of the projects and SignalR.Client in the others that are connecting to that Hub.
This solution is hosted on two servers, and I have a strange problem. In one server everything works fine, but in the other i get an 404 not found error when I am trying to establish the connection from the SignalR.Client.

Hub Code:

```
public class GlobalHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }


    public void Notify(string user,NotificationViewModel model)
    {
        Clients.Group(user).notify(model);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Env.UserId().ToString();
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);            
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Global.asax Hub Map:

```
 var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
        };
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("/signalr",hubConfiguration);
```

The connection attempt:

```
string portal = CommonHelper.GetPortalUrl("user");
        if(portal.Contains(":50150"))
        {
            portal = portal.Replace(":50150", "");
        }

        var connection = new HubConnection(portal+"signalr",false);
        IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("GlobalHub");

        connection.Start().Wait(); 

        myHub.Invoke("Notify", userID.ToString(), result2);
```

I am pretty sure that my connection url is correct, I checked it 50 times.

Error occurs on this line:

```
onnection.Start().Wait();
```

SS of Error:
[image: 404 not found error]

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess: Don't you need a slash there: `new HubConnection(portal+"/signalr",false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I solved the problem. It turned out that it was a problem with the server. The server itself couldnt recognize that url (throws 404 on the url). 
After that problem was fixed, SignalR started working

Comment: How did you make the server recognize that that URL exists?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that when hosting a SignalR project on two servers, clients connected to one can only be connected to other clients connected to the same server. That is because SignalR doesn't automatically broadcast a message through all servers.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Try have a look here and I hope it is helpful to you. One of the proposed solution is to use the Redis Pub/Sub (http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) solution, or Azure Service Bus (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) - both of whom are use as a backplane (when a server receives a message, it is broadcast to all of them and the one that needs it can use it).

Comment: Tnx for the answer its a very good one, yet this doesnt solve my problem since I dont want to broadcast on both servers in paralel. Im using SignalR per server, and it doesnt collude with the other server.